# Prove that the determinant of the matrix is equal to 0

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let the $n\times n$-matrix $A$ have $s$ rows and $t$ columns such that all the elements at their intersection are equal to $0$ and $s + t > n$. Prove that the determinant of the matrix is equal to $0$.

Comment: Can you show those $s$ rows are linearly dependent?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Each row has t zeros at the same positions, so there're no more than n - t such linearly independent rows, but s > n - t, so these rows are linearly dependent, so the determinant of the matrix A is 0.